# Trying to connect to mysql database through workbench but workbench is not opening

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwXU.png)
I am trying to connect to the database using the workbench (screenshot attached), but it is not opening. It is saying "opening SQL editor" but does not open. I have uninstalled and installed MySQL several times, yet it is not working. I can connect DB using the command prompt. The first time when I installed it, it was working fine. When I opened it, I thought I forgot the password and uninstalled and reinstalled and asked for the password. Somehow I got the password. Unfortunately, pasting the password, I pasted the hell of a lot of .log file info in the password field, and after that, I am facing the issue.

Comment: There is a bug logged 228 days before "Cannot access a disposed object - 'HudForm'". Is this bug casing this nonfunctioning?

Comment: Did you need workbench? I give up trying to use Workbench, is really very good but came with a lot of problems. I switch to DBeaver https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: Thank you, @HectorVido. I have downloaded and installed it. Working fine.

Comment: Is a good think get used with terminal interface too :) give a chance to the black screen!